# Gnu Make : Slice variable (keep all but last element)

Tags: makefile, build, slice, gnu-make

I'm trying to perform a slice on a variable in my makefile.
I use this :

```
C_SOURCES := $(foreach dir, $(C_SOURCEDIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
```

To generate a list of all the code source files and then use this:

```
C_OBJS := $(subst $(C_SOURCEDIR), $(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR), $(C_SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
```

To generate all the names of all the associated object files. However, the build directory itself (CLIENT_BUILD_DIR) keeps appearing as the last element of C_OBJS. (I'm also not entirely sure why this happens...)

As a sort of hack I've decided I would remove the last element of C_OBJS (slice it away, keeping all the n - 1 first elements), and attempted doing so like this:

```
C_OBJS := $(wordlist, 1, $(words $(C_OBJS)) - 1, $(C_OBJS))
```

However this results in C_OBJS being empty !
I have read the [documentation for text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), but unless I'm not understanding something properly this should work as expected: make C_OBJS = all the elements in C_OBJS except the last one.

Any help appreciated ! (And a bonus cookie for anyone who can explain *why* CLIENT_BUILD_DIR appears in C_OBJS in the first place; and potentially how to avoid it)[EDIT: see answer for that part]

If needed this is the full segement of the makefile in question:

```
CLIENT_SRC_DIR   := $(SOURCEDIR)/Client
CLIENT_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILDDIR)/Client
C_DIRS           := $(notdir $(shell find $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR) -type d -print | tail -n +2))
C_SOURCEDIRS     := $(foreach dir, $(C_DIRS), $(addprefix $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/, $(dir)))
C_TARGETDIRS     := $(foreach dir, $(C_DIRS), $(addprefix $(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/, $(dir)))
C_SOURCES        := $(foreach dir, $(C_SOURCEDIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
C_OBJS           := $(subst $(C_SOURCEDIR), $(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR), $(C_SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
C_OBJS           := $(wordlist, 1, $(words $(C_OBJS)) - 1, $(C_OBJS))
C_DEPS           := $(C_OBJS:.o=.d)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Instead of fixing the unwanted properties of `wildcard` you may want to take a look at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-wildcard-reclist-of-globs . Maybe you can formulate directly what you want instead of detouring with ad-hoc `make` programming.

Comment: BTW: your wish to calculate length-1 in `$(words $(C_OBJS)) - 1` as second parameter for the `wordlist` function is ill-fated, as `make` doesn't know how to calculate. It receives a string `123 - 1` which it fails to translate into an integer and so the evaluation of `wordlist` fails too. Coincidentally the gmtt-Library can calculate too, although as I said IMHO here it is better to formulate directly what you try to achieve.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Oh you're right about the - 1 ! (And I'll look into gmtt thanks !) But I'm assuming I could also get the job done using bash then no ? I don't actually know if it's possible to have bash in a makefile interact with the make variables

Comment: It is possible to do it with command line tools (also the calculation thing). You are tying your makefile to a bash system then, tho. Plus, for high-frequency calls to bash there may arise also performance issues.

Comment: I recommend you do not use `subst` for this.  You should use `patsubst`: `$(patsubst $(C_SOURCEDIR)/%,$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/%,$(C_SOURCES:.cpp=.o))`.  It's much safer.

Comment: @MadScientist I've read the documentation, but I don't really see when to choose between `patsubst` and `subst`, any advice; or reason you say `patsubst` is better here ?

Comment: `subst` will replace ALL occurrences of the word.  So if your file is `src/mysrc.c` and your `C_SOURCEDIR` is `src` and `C_BUILD_DIR` is `obj`, then `subst` will return `obj/myobj.c` which is not what you want.  `patsubst` replaces only the matched pattern, once, so it will do the right thing here.

Comment: Oh ! Subtle but I hadn't thought about that, sharp as always !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vroomfondel's comment I realized the 'slice' was not working simply because make was treating strings, and as such didn't know what the -1 meant.

On another note: there is (it's somehow always these types of mistakes that take the longest to fix) a typo in the C_OBJS line; `C_SOURCEDIR` is not a variable that exists ! So make treats it as an empty string, which in turns makes the `subst` command not work as intended...

Lesson: Watch out for the *ninja typos*

Answer (score 0):

This will evaluate to all but the last word of `$(VAR)`:

```
VAR2 := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(VAR)),x $(VAR))
```

You can also make it into a function:

```
define firstwords
$(wordlist 2,$(words $(1)),x $(1))
endef

VAR2 := $(call firstwords,$(VAR))
```